# PayPal In context Express Checkout starts redirecting to full page PayPal login

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've had the in context paypal flow working in sandbox mode but it just seems to have suddenly started redirecting to the full page paypal page now for what seems like no reason at all.

It first shows the in context popup and fairly quickly displays the log output below.  It then spins the circle for another 35 seconds and finally redirects to www.sandbox.paypal.com full page login.

It redirects to this after approx. 35 seconds:
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/hermes/fallback?product=ec&reason=hermes_to_legacy&fallback=1&incontext=1&token=EC-2JW68939JV301205H

I enabled logging and the console shows these:

```
PayPal Incontext is running in sandbox mode. This message will not appear in production mode

[post-robot] fullpage mysite.com #receive postrobot_message_request identify Object {hash: "identify_a5696077b9", type: "postrobot_message_request", name: "identify", data: Object, id: "cbcd06def6"…}data: Objecthash: "identify_a5696077b9"id: "cbcd06def6"name: "identify"originalSource: "PPFrameefdd3d7440"originalWindowType: "popup"source: "PPFrameefdd3d7440"type: "postrobot_message_request"windowType: "popup"__proto__: Object

[post-robot] fullpage mysite.com #send postrobot_message_ack identify Object     {target: "PPFrameefdd3d7440", hash: "identify_a5696077b9", name: "identify", type: "postrobot_message_ack", id: "fade8375aa"…}

[post-robot] fullpage mysite.com #send postrobot_message_response identify Object {target: "PPFrameefdd3d7440", hash: "identify_a5696077b9", name: "identify", type: "postrobot_message_response", ack: "success"…}

[post-robot] fullpage mysite.com #receive postrobot_message_request init Object {hash: "init_7572e25d03", type: "postrobot_message_request", name: "init", data: Object, id: "0d5dae02bd"…}

[post-robot] fullpage mysite.com #send postrobot_message_ack init Object {target: "PPFrameefdd3d7440", hash: "init_7572e25d03", name: "init", type: "postrobot_message_ack", id: "c5f5cd0f26"…}

[post-robot] fullpage mysite.com #send postrobot_message_response init Object {target: "PPFrameefdd3d7440", hash: "init_7572e25d03", name: "init", type: "postrobot_message_response", ack: "success"…}

[post-robot] fullpage mysite.com #receive postrobot_message_request return Object {hash: "return_4f3cdfcba1", type: "postrobot_message_request", name: "return", data: Object, id: "61dc3dc8ec"…}

[post-robot] fullpage mysite.com #send postrobot_message_ack return Object {target: "PPFrameefdd3d7440", hash: "return_4f3cdfcba1", name: "return", type: "postrobot_message_ack", id: "6c96a77ba8"…}
```

How do you find out what is causing the full redirect and ensure it uses in context?  I don't understand why it pauses for some 35 seconds either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same thing happening the past two days. Today seems to be going better. I sometimes get the lightbox payment going through instead of the full page. I think Paypal's load is heavy and sandbox users get less server priority. I think it falling back to legacy is part of this. Waiting it out worked for me but maybe other people know better? I have a feeling if I switch to production the lightbox will work fine. But that's the whole point of a sandbox isn't it, to emulate real life situations. Paypal needs to get their stuff together.

Comment: Well I just tried it again first thing this morning and it seems to be working ok.  I guess someone had to switch the server off and on again :\